# Applying advice on Spring provided class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am able to apply below aspect on Employee class but not on spring inbuilt class`DelegatingMessageSource`. Here is the aspect definition

```
    @Aspect
    @Component
    public class LogCustomAspect {

         //It does not work
         @Before("execution(* org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource.getMessage(..))")
        public void logResponse1(JoinPoint jp) {
             System.out.println("Inside logResponse1");
         }

         // It works
         @Before("execution(* com.myproject.Employee.getEmployee(..))")
        public void logResponse2(JoinPoint jp) {
             System.out.println("logResponse2");
         }
    }
```

I am not sure what i am missing here and how to apply asspect spring provided class ?

Comment: (Hi Emilly. It looks like your profile contains a request to merge profiles. The other account seems to be deleted, so I assume this is done, and the message can be removed?)

Answer (score 0):

Usually when Spring AOP cannot be applied on a class the reason is that the class is not a Spring bean/component. Maybe this applies to `DelegatingMessageSource`, as a non-Spring user I have not checked. If this is not the reason (some Spring experts might be able to tell you) probably you have a configuration issue.

But if my assumption is true, the only way to weave an aspect into that class is by configuring Spring to use full [AspectJ via LTW (load-time weaving)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj). AspectJ does not rely on dynamic proxies but directly weaves into the original class's bytecode.

Comment: It can not be configuration issue as I said its working for custom classes.  Yes first reason you stated can be true but not sure how can I confirm it as it's spring inbuilt class/configuration ?

Comment: I did not say it was. My assumption is that it is not a spring component but just a pojo class. The other statement only applies if I am wrong. But I think I am right. As for your second question, just look through all superclasses and implemented interfaces and check if there is e.g. a `@Component` annotation. Or loop through a list of all active components/beans during runtime and check if that class is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Since `DelegatingMessageSource` is not a spring managed bean, aspects wont be applied to it. Here is the code for your reference [DelegatingMessageSource](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/DelegatingMessageSource.java).

What I would suggest is try defining a bean of `DelegatingMessageSource` in one of your `@Configuration` classes. Maybe this will work :

```
@Bean
public HierarchicalMessageSource messageSource() {
    return new DelegatingMessageSource();
}
```